# C++ List Insert Iterator

Tags: c++, list

A family object contains a linked list of Person objects, and as such, a function exists within the Family class to insert Person objects into a ListedList called people.

I’m having some trouble where only certain Person objects are being added to the people linked list. I have omitted a number of other functions, as I was (hopefully) able to determine the problem is occurring within the `insertPerson()` function in the Family class.

The for loop within `insertPacket()` is looping through each ‘Person’ object as intended (refer to commented ‘cout’). However, things break down in the if statement..

```
if (person_id < itr->get_person_id())
      {
         Person *psn = new Person(person_id, name);
         people.insert(itr, *psn);
         break;
      }
```

If a `person_id` is less than the `get_person_id()` in the linked list, it executes and inserts it at the beginning of the list, however if it is not, it just skips it entirely...

Comment: Still reading your question, but you should probably fix the memory leaks, of which there are at least three. And I see no implementation of `insertPacket` called from `createPerson`. I only see `insertPerson`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. You are saying that if a `person_id` is less than any person's id in the `list` that it adds, and if the id isn't less it "skips it entirely". That appears to be what your code is doing, but what are you trying to have it do?

Comment: Implementation of insertPacket - I am using header files to declare each function, didn’t show here to simplify. Is this what you’re referring to?

Memory leaks - would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction?

Aim is to insert the person objects into the list in ascending order, based on the person_id.

Comment: Don't simplify to the point code is uncompilable and cannot reproduce your problem. The point of an [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is to *reproduce* the undesirable behavior of your current code with the *minimal* amount of code needed to do so in hopes of fixing it. To do that, unless the problem is glaringly obvious, we need enough code to cut, paste, compile, and run (ideally against a data sample that reproduces your problem). The current posting is *not* an MCVE. Regarding your memory leaks, nowhere I see in this code is `new` required.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks bringing me up to speed. I have updated the code to include everything, as well as some initial data. 

I have changed the object creation to automatic memory.

If run, you should see that only two People are being inserted into the family, not the intended three..

Comment: Thanks for the updated source. (and kudos for fixing your memory leaks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fundamental bug is here, in `insertPerson`:

```
for(itr = people.begin(); itr != people.end(); itr++)
{
    if (id < itr->get_person_id())
    {
        people.insert(itr, Person(id, text));
        break;
    }
}
```

What if the person's id is greater than *all* of the current list members? Then the `insert` will never happen as you will reach `end()` and break the loop. This should be used to find the insertion point, which can *include* `end()`.

You can find the proper insertion point doing this:

```
for(itr = people.begin(); itr != people.end(); itr++)
{
    if (itr->get_person_id() < id)
        break;
}
people.insert(itr, Person(id, text));
```

Note that this **will** allow duplicate insertions for a given id. Not sure if you care about that. Finally, the same problem exists for insertion of a `Family`, so you probably want to fix that after this.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   if (input_id < itr->get_familyid())
   {
         Family *fam = new Family(input_id);
         families.insert(itr, *fam);
         break;
   }
```

std::list insert according to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/) link is

```
iterator insert (iterator position, const value_type& val);
```

Comment: I strongly advise *fixing* the memory leak.